# Google Apps Script Listbox Behavior with setId()?

Tags: google-apps-script

A bit new to Google Apps scripting but I am seeing what appears to be strange behavior with the `listBox` class. Here's a LARGER snippet of the script:

```
var storeNameHandler = app.createServerHandler("newStoreHandler");
var storeNameLabel = app.createHTML("<BR /><B>Which store or site:</B>");
var LB_storeName = app.createListBox().setId('storeName').setName('storeName');
LB_storeName.addChangeHandler(storeNameHandler);
// Get the stores on the budget sheet.
var stores = budgetSheet.getRange("H2:H").getValues();
// add items to ListBox
LB_storeName.addItem("");
LB_storeName.addItem("NEW STORE/SITE");
stores.forEach(function(item){
    if(item!="") LB_storeName.addItem(item);
});
```

Here's the onChange handler:

```
function newStoreHandler(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var storeNameListBox = app.getElementById('storeName');
  storeNameListBox.setVisible(false);
  var newStoreNameInput = app.getElementById('newStoreName');
  newStoreNameInput.setVisible(true);
}
```

The idea is to have the listbox disappear and a text entry box appear in the same place (or just below, whatever is possible) onChange.  I'll add logic to the handler to determine which choice will result in the listbox hide/input reveal event happens once I get this working.

When I inspect the generated listbox element, it shows the ***name*** as `storeName` but no ID. The listbox comes up as expected from the data in the spreadsheet.  Shouldn't the **setId()** method add the ***id*** tag to the listbox as it does for ***name*** (see below)?

The listbox as reported by inspect element:

```
<select class="gwt-ListBox" name="storeName">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="NEW STORE/SITE">NEW STORE/SITE</option>
  <option value="Costco">Costco</option>
  <option value="Amazon.com">Amazon.com</option>
  <option value="Woot.com">Woot.com</option>
</select>
```

Note the distinct lack of an ***id*** but clearly ***name*** is being set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the behaviour that I see, and  would expect, from UiApp as the Ui's html is not designed to be manipulated outside the app itself. Hence, id does not have significance to user or app developer.
If you want more control over your app's html, avoid UiApp (which is not being developed further).

Comment: It is perfectly fine to use the `UiApp`. Only few widgets were deprecated. Furthermore, the label that's being created (with the `createHTML`) has no relation to the `listBox`.

Comment: Yes, I know the label has no relation to the listbox.  Now, may I ask the original answerer here what I SHOULD use if UiApp is no longer being developed?  Also -- as far as I can tell, I am not manipulating the HTML outside of the app.  I'm using handlers within the script to (try to) manipulate the generated HTML.  And if this is true, what exactly was the setId() method included in this class at all?

Comment: @KCL DavidF is referring to this: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/

Comment: @KCL as Jacob points out , *I* think that if you wish to manipulate html within GAS then use the htmlservice for your ui. The UiApp component is a couple of steps removed from html as you will see when you examine the page source - the id appears as a parameter. UiApp of course is perfectly ok for use,*if* it does what you want however do not expect it to change in functionality to meet perceived shortcomings. Whatever uses setId has, they do not include setting the id on the html element on displayed page.

Comment: @KCL The setId() function is basically set so you can then access the widget using [UiInstance.getElementById(id)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/ui-instance#getElementById(String))

Comment: I've added some code and clarification to the initial post.  If the answer is truly that UiApp isn't useful here, I'll move on.  Thanks for all the help so far!

Comment: I am certain that the answer to "Shouldn't the setId() method add the id tag to the listbox as it does for name ?" is NO. Despite looking like an id tag, it is a reference to object in the g-apps script. The script has done its work and *then* the html is created. Even if you could think of a use for the id within the generated html (like applying custom css), it is highly unlikely to be developed as Google have said they are not developing UiApp further.  The main use for the getElementById(id) is in handlers where you receive references to widgets by name but operate on them by id.

Comment: I ended up moving away from UIApp for all the reasons cited.  Using a template was far and away simpler and worked like a charm.